# While Loop in C#

Tags: c#, while-loop, console-application

I want to exit from a loop when both `i` and `j` have the value 6, but it exits when one of them has the value `6`.

```cs
int i,j,k;
i=k=0;
j=1;
Random num = new Random();
Console.WriteLine("Please Press any Key to Roll");
while((i!=6)&&(j!=6))
{
    Console.ReadKey();
    i= num.Next(0,7);
    j= num.Next(0,7);
    Console.WriteLine("1st Rolled Number is: "+ i);
    Console.WriteLine("2st Rolled Number is: "+ j);
    k++;
}
Console.WriteLine("Your have achieved it in "+ k + " Atempts");
```

Answer (score 5):

To exit the loop when both i and j have the value 6, you can change the condition in the while loop to

Change too

```
while ((i != 6) || (j != 6))
```

This will exit the loop when either i or j. To exit the loop when both i and j have the value 6,

```
while (!(i == 6 && j == 6))
```

This will exit the loop when both i and j have the value 6.

Answer (score 1):

In other words, the loop should continue if either `i` isn't 6 or `j` isn't 6 - this is a logical or (`||`) condition, not a logical and (`&&`) condition:

```cs
while ((i != 6) || (j != 6))
```

Answer (score 0):

an alternative approach can be

```
while(true)
{
    Console.ReadKey();
    i = num.Next(0, 7);
    j = num.Next(0, 7);
    Console.WriteLine("1st Rolled Number is: " + i);
    Console.WriteLine("2st Rolled Number is: " + j);
    k++;
    if (i == 6 && j == 6) break;
}
Console.WriteLine("You have achieved it in " + k + " attempts");
```